# Doctrine: Is it possible to INDEX BY a related field?

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, many-to-one

I have a Doctrine model (`Assignment`), which has a many-to-one relationship with another model (`Region`). Assignments are owned by users (with each user having only one assignment per region at a time), and I am trying to use `indexBy` to have the user's array of assignments be keyed by the ID of the assignment's region. However, I only get standard 0..n numeric keys.

When I try to run a DQL query like `SELECT am, reg, user FROM Assignment am INDEX BY [...] JOIN am.region reg JOIN am.user user WHERE user.id = ?1`, none of these values for INDEX BY work:

- `region` (Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.)
- `region_id` (Error: Class ...\Assignment has no field or association named region_id)
- `region.id` (Error: Expected end of string, got '.')

Is this possible? If not, then what would be a convenient way to access a `User`'s assignment on a region without `indexBy`?

Comment: could you please post the models and relations between them?

Comment: I encounter the same kind of problem, except i got a `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 121 near 'alert WHERE clientAlert.client': Error: 'alert' is already defined.`.

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the same problem today. Fortunately I've found the solution : )

First of all, you have to declare additional column in ORM mapping:

```
Abdulklarapl\My\EntityA:
type: entity
table: entityA
manyToOne:
    entityB:
        targetEntity: EntityB
        joinColumn:
            name: label_id
            referencedColumnName: id
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    value:
        type: text
    entityB_id:
        type: integer
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

notice that I've declared `entityB_id` as a **field** + I've configured **manyToOne** relation by adding a `joinColumn` clause

so now you can use entityB_id as scalar value

```
$doctrine->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('c')
        ->from('AbdulklaraplMyBundle:EntityA', 'c', 'c.entityB_id')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

it will return assoc array

```
[
    c.entityB_id: {
        id: "",
        value: ""
        entityB_id: ""
    }
]
```

you can also use `AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY` as a argument for `getResult()` - it will return assoc array with array instead the objects

Answer (score 2):

If you need to INDEX BY a foreign key e.g. "region_id" it is possible in your mapping:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Region", mappedBy="user", indexBy="region_id")
 */
protected $regions;
```

The feature was [added here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/639).

Unfortunately it does not seem to be documented that you have to use the name of the column of the foreign key itself.

[Working with Indexed Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html)

Answer (score -2):

Import the Query class (optional):

```
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query;
```

Create the query:

```
$query = $this->data->em->createQuery('
    SELECT a 
    FROM Assignment a 
    INDEX BY a.reg //to set array custom key
    WHERE a.user = :user');
$query->setParameter('user', 3); //user with id 3

//set the hidration mode in order to work with read-only arrays
$assignments = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: I tried using this query, but it gave the same "Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression."